# PHP GD: Fill rectangle with existing image

Tags: php, gd, image-manipulation

I have an image created with `imagecreate(300, 380);`. Now, I want to "draw" another image (from file) in a defined rectangle on this image I just created.

How can I get this done?

Comment: http://php.net/imagecopy

Comment: that's to easy :P

Comment: yes it is, except maybe for the function's name :-)

Comment: You've shown no research effort at all.  What have you tried so far? Please add your code to your question.